# How to get the CMOS inverter's open-loop gain

Tags: loop-gain

In 74LVC1GU04's [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74LVC1GU04.pdf), section: 13. Application information

[image]

The equation to get close loop gain need the loop gain \$G_{OL}\$, but i've no way to get this value from the datasheet. Can this value be acquired from the digits given in the datasheet, or i need to measure it by myself?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

**Update:**

In NXP's another CMOS inverter: 74HCU04's [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HCU04.pdf), i find this (thanks to MarkU):

[image]

So maybe it's a typo of 74LVC1GU04's datasheet. That is, \$G_{OL} = A_{OL}\$. Anyone can conform this?

Comment: How about simulating it?

Comment: I can't find the linear amplifier model of it.

Comment: Diverger, I don`t know if your problem is solved now - or not (because of the error in the data sheet). However, I still have problems to understand the meaning of "Gol=20 (typical)". With a transconductance of app. 40mA/V (data sheet) the corresponding load resistance would be app. RL=20/(40mA/V)=500 ohms. This in contradiction to the given value of ZL>10kohms.

Comment: Diverger-regarding a model for simulation: Some time ago I simply have used two symmetrical complementary MOSFETS for realizing such a CMOS stage.

Comment: Um, when CMOS inverter is biased, the output impedance should be large, but how large? When giving \$A_{OL}\$, it limits \$Z_{L} > 10k \Omega\$, so \$Z_{L}\$ maybe very very large, can be larger than the output impedance right? So, i guess, the output impedance is less than \$10k \Omega\$, and maybe very smaller than that, so it can give a relative constant \$A_{OL}\$. Am i right? What do think?

Comment: And about the model. Does it need some more parameters to model the PMOS and NMOS? Such as L, W, K? And need i extract some parameter from the datasheet? Can you give me some information about how to model the inverter from the datasheet, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typo in the 74LVC1GU04 datasheet. Open-loop gain GOL in the equation is listed at AOL=20(typical) in the second to last line about ZL>10kohm. Refer to the parent device http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HCU04.pdf which is the hex version of this (newer) single unbuffered inverter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think, some confusion could arise with regard to the different gain terms. At first, in Fig.12 the term **Gol** is the so-called **loop gain**, which is the gain of all loop components (to be measured/simulated when the loop is opened). In contrast, the **open-loop gain** **Aol** is the gain of the amplifier unit when there is no signal feedback. In Fig. 12 there is another gain term called **voltage amplification** **Au**. I think, the difference between Aol and Au is as follows:

- Aol is the gain (without signal feedback, R1=0) but with ZL and R2 connected because both impedances determine the gain (The CMOS inverter has a large output resistance). The resistor R2 is necessary to fix a bias point (otherwise no gain can be defined) and the parallel combination of both values act as a load for the high-resistive output.
- I presume that the term Au describes the slope of the (theoretical) CMOS transfer characteristics, which - however - cannot be exploited because an operating point must be fixed using DC feedback (which reduces the slope and, thus, the gain). That means: Au>Aol.

Question: Which gain are you interested in?

Comment: Actually, i mean \$A_{OL}\$. But i think the datasheet also mean \$A_{OL}\$ too.

Comment: Aol is given in Fig. 12 with app. Aol=20. This value depends on Au as well as on ZL and R2. Without these values the given value for Aol cannot be verified.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Maybe the datasheet is confused about \$G_{OL}\$ and \$A_{OL}\$? That is, \$G_{OL}\$ just is \$A_{OL}\$? In MarkU's answer, there only \$G_{OL}\$, no \$A_{OL}\$.

Comment: If the output impedance is much larger than the load, then \$Z_{L}\$ should have little effect on \$A_{OL}\$, right?

Comment: No - the opposite is true. In case of a (non-ideal) current output it is the connected load that determines the output voltage primarily.